# retrieve last 2 rows from a table in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working a website.And i want this query for a particular functionality.I have tried it but it is not working.

how to retrieve last 2 rows from a table in MySQL??

I want a query in MySQL.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: May be you should open your Database Concepts book again!! And look for the topic LIMIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, type, details from supportContacts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 helps you retrieve last two rows

Answer (score 1):

SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 2

Answer (score 0):

Whats your table structure?
is there any date time field to get last records?
Is there any primary key?

If primary key then you could use:

```
Select * from table_name order by primary_key_column desc limit 2;
```

Comment: Oh, don't encourage them